# Minimize window in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, maximize-window

I've created a frame and set it extended state to `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`. The window appears maximazed at startup, but after I pressed "Restore" button, it resizes to zero-sized window with only upper part, which contains minimize, maximize and close buttons. After that I can resize window manually, and the content is shown.

I want my window to be maximized at startup, but don't want to lose it after restore button click.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame { 
      public MyFrame() {
         //...
         setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);        
         setVisible(true);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `pack()` before `setVisible(true)` to make sure the preferred size is properly calculated. I think then restore should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should try this:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame { 
      public MyFrame() {
         //...
         setSize(500,400); // Watever size you want to set.
         setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);        
         setVisible(true);
      }
}
```